# Rails file upload gem like Paperclip, without the ImageMagick dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Is there a `Paperclip` gem alternative, which does not require ImageMagick, for Rails 3.2.x projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) have easy uploader interface.

There are RMagick and MiniMagic implemetations of thumbnail generators.

[MiniMagic](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#using-minimagick) allows you to have the power of ImageMagick without having to worry about installing all the RMagick libraries:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
end
```